# Laravel echo does not recieve event from web socket

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I really need some help cause its been 5 days searching on how to fix this issue.

**The issue**: I'm trying to make a simple realtime web with laravel. vue, laravel-websocket(BeyondCode) and mysql. If you open the project and try to submit the form, the data enters the database and the event is sent to the websocket. The problem is, vue doesn't respond to the event and update the view.

Would really appreciate if someone look into this.TYSM

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P1a8HO2KQzoJiquvQMIP7vl7RvVIrNyx

Comment: You should provide the snippet or code sample or show some errors instead of sharing a link to download the entire project.

Comment: Downing a zip file is risk and someone should not have to download anything to help. Post code please.

Answer (score 1):

That's an example Broadcast Channel. check your channel is working or not.
Exmple of vue js listing Laravel Socket.

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in desserts" :key="index">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  props: ["item"],
data() {
    return {      
      desserts: []
      // array Decalare 
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.listenForBroadcast(
      {
        channelName: "channelName",
        eventName: "eventName"
      },
      ({ data }) => {
        this.desserts = data.data.stockData;
        // store in desserts array
      }
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the channel is working and the websocket recieve the event but vue doesnt